# Get nth-of-type to NOT target children of children?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to target an `<h1>` element within a `<div>` using the CSS `first-of-type` property, but I noticed that not only does this target the first child of this `<div>` that is of type `<h1>`, but it also targets the children of children that are of type `<h1>`, which seems less useful to me. Is there any way that children of children can be excluded from this?

In the example below, I have an `<h1>` that's an immediate child of a `<div>` called `#everything`. I try targeting that `<h1>` in the CSS, but this results in targeting both the correct `<h1>` as well as another `<h1>` within a child `<div>`.

```css
#everything h1:first-of-type{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="everything">
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <div id="something">
      <h1>goodbye</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: #everything > h1:first-child{
  color: red;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```css
#everything>h1:first-of-type{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="everything">
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <div id="something">
      <h1>goodbye</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your css code with this.

```
#everything > h1{
    color: red;
}
```

One more option:

```
#everything:first-child > h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

For this option **#everything:first-child** you need to specify the child **h1** or it's **class/id.**